# jQuery width display issue

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, width

I'm trying to get the width of an element with jQuery and then paste it into a span.
Thing is the `.width()` gives me the width in pixels, but what I want is the width is percentual.
What I'm trying to do is to get the width of a progressbar and paste it into a span but this line `var wit = progress.find(".ui-progressbar-value").width();` will give me the value in pixels. Anyway to have that value in % instead?

Comment: What is your end goal? I have WAY too much practice with the progress bar, and what you're trying to achive is probably alot easier than the way you're going about it.  Can you provide more info on what you're doing?

Comment: For instance, the width of your "range" or `.ui-progressbar-value` as you're getting too, is proportional to the max range meaning you can easily just use the value itself in small simple math to get a "percentage" if needed.

Comment: I have a progress bar with buttons to add and remove 5% value to it. The bas an if or else script to 'read' the value and fade in a text and/or change the color of the bar itself. It's pretty much compleated I just want to include a text inside the bar that it'll show the current percent. Here's the link to what I have done so far: http://daokun.webs.com/jQuery/Progress.html the stopwatch is just something I was playing with.

Comment: As I expected, from what I can see you're using the base which sets the max at 100% meaning you can simply fetch the value: `$("#progressBar").progressbar('value')` and add the percent tag: `$("#progressBar").progressbar('value') + "%"` just that simple

Comment: FYI had a thing there a min ago about multply 10, scratch that, it's a monday and I had a brain fart

Comment: Lol s'ok. I did it now the only thing remaining is to make that span follow the value bar by editing the right css atribute, maybe... I tried adding .css('right', 'witPct') but doesn't work... any idea?

Comment: P.S. Sorry I'm still learning about JS and jQuery..

Comment: and to put it inside the bar, use `create: function(e, ui){` to add an inner span when creating the bar, then use `change: function..` to change what the text in the span is as the bar is changed.  I can show ya an example if you'd like, I have sever progress bars that do this, including one that shows the number in the actual range slider (the little ball you grab on the demo page)

Comment: bleh now i'm mixing pbar and slider, thoughts, anyway, both work much the same, can still sow you a dozen explinations and examples, as my company sight usess these things like cheese at a cracker factory

Comment: looking for one now, brb in 5 or so

Comment: xD Tyt, I hope I can handle Js and jQuery as a Pro one day

Comment: made it an answer, so it's easier to find, incase you're reading this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, took me a minute trying to find example, finally i just said "screwit" and made you a fresh fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/3n3Mb/

It shows first hand how to:

- Add a text spot to your progress bar (note the use of position absolute on the span)

  - *You do not want to add this to your "value" bar as it wont show on 0%*
- Update text on change
- make use of setInterval to change the value every second (just for kicks)

FYI: with a little use of css, you could position it anywhere on the bar you want pretty easy, just hit this up if you need more help with that too

Comment: Ty but do you know a way to have the text placed just some pixels away from the edge of the value bar?

Comment: Yes but on the other side.. xD

Comment: That would work fine but I don't know how to integrate it into my code to make it work :s

Comment: I rearanged it (the fiddle) to put text on left of progress bar value end (except at 0 of course).  If you need a full break down of what is doing what to maybe incorporate it into your project easier, i'll try and provide one later when i have more time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get jQuery to give you a percentage, but you can easily compute one. Get the item's width, then divide it by the container's width, then multiply that ratio by 100 and round it:

```
var witPct = Math.round(100 * wit / progress.width());
```

Comment: Anyway you know that I can make the span follow the value bar by adding .css('right')?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the percentage on your own by taking the width of the wrapping element for example. To give you an good answer it might help if you include some of your code.